# Trying to get the Total results count crashes the /notifications path

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.1, notifications

I am trying to use the filter `!9ciXfDSYM` (same as default but with `total`) [with the `/notifications` request and the response is](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications#filter=!9ciXfDSYM):

> {   "error_id": 500,   "error_name": "internal_error",
>   "error_message": "this error has been logged" }

It seems that this applies to notifications only, because `/inbox` with the same filter works flawlessly.

Comment: Confirmed buggy behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Sorry about the wait, a fix was actually staged a few days ago but deploying it was delayed by our yearly company get together.